# drupal user interface to add a new database

Tags: php, drupal, database-connection

I am working with drupal and my idea is to create a module that offers to user an interface to define a new database parameters, so the user interface will be some drupal forms where the user have to give database name, username, password...and submitt. Is it possibe to get the submitted values and put them into an array in the same module and then use the new array to connect to the database and perform some queries operations?

```
<?php
// drupal forms to fill the database parameters
// submitt the values
// insert the submitted velues into the following array:
  $other_database = array(
      'database' => databasename,
      'username' => username,
      'password' => psw,
      'host' => host,
      'port' => port,
      'driver' => drv,
      'prefix' => '',
 );
  /
  Database::addConnectionInfo(databasename, 'default', $other_database);
  db_set_active(databasename);

  // execute queries here
  db_set_active(); // without the paramater means set back to the default for the site
  drupal_set_message(t('The queries have been made.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

check out hook_menu and form api, here's the tutorial page, https://drupal.org/node/262422

Comment: thx but I have already created the form Iam only asking if it is possible to collect the user subbmitted values to create a new database array and connect to it?or the database initialisation should be only defined in the settings.php file?